# How to access a k8s service from different cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am new in the Kubernetes world. I am using Google Cloud.

I have two cluster and within the cluster, I can communicate service to service by DNS name. But I can't get access if I try to communicate from another cluster.

Example:

In ClusterA:

Namespace: namespaceA

Service: serviceA

I can able to access it like: serviceA.namespaceA.svc.cluster.local

In ClusterB:
I can't access it like serviceA.namespaceA.svc.cluster.local

I understood it doesn't allow access from different cluster.

Is there any way to make it accessible? [N.B: I don't want to expose it publicly. I need it access amoung the cluster.]

Comment: Kubernetes resources (including Services including DNS) are cluster-specific. You will need to expose the Service's endpoint beyond the cluster (A) with an IP on a network that is accessible (possibly via DNS) within the remote cluster (B). There are various ways to do this. Search for Kubernetes `NodePort`, `LoadBalancer`, Ingress and Gateway API.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for the answer.

I setup ingress, but the problem is now I can access it from the browser using ingress IP, which I don't want to.

Comment: This might help: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that is built in to Kubernetes by default. However,

You can achieve what you want by installing a service mesh that supports multi-cluster. Istio supports this use case. Here is some documentation that explains it:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary/

The other option is to put both clusters on the same private network (such as on the same VPC, using VPC peering, or with some other means) and then enable access to the services across clusters through internal load balancers or node ports.